# PhpStorm/JavaScript Expression statement is not assignment or call

Tags: javascript, vue.js, phpstorm

I'm trying to make a method the cleanest I can.

Depending on what a integer number is, I'm creating a different date format, so I end up having this:

```js
getRanges() {
            var currentDate = new Date();
            //Esto seguro que se puede simplificar
            const format = (format) => {
                this.formatedTimeRange.start = moment(new Date(currentDate.getTime() - this.timeRange * 60000)
                    , "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(format);
                this.formatedTimeRange.end = moment(new Date(this.linesData[0].x[this.linesData[0].x.length-1])
                    , "YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ").format(format);
            }

            const Ranges = {
                '1': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                '5': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                '15': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
                '60': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                '180': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                '360': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                '720': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                '1440': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm"),
                '2880': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH"),
                '10080': format("YYYY-MM-DD HH"),
                '43200': format("YYYY-MM-DD"),
            }

            Ranges[this.timeRange];
        }
```

But I get this warning message:

> Expression statement is not assignment or call in line `Ranges[this.timeRange]`;

P.S. The code works fine.

Comment: What was the purpose of that line of code that IDE is worried about? You just got something from Ranges object and not doing anything with it, nor `return`ing, nor executing anything, thats all IDE is telling about.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to return this value, you have to add the expression "return" or if you want to print the `Range[this.timeRange];` you should add the "print" expression. Alternatively you can just take this line out, because as the comment above i dont really see the purpose of this line.

Answer (score 0):

You're formatting your data with every possible format, every time, but it seems you wanted to pick one specific format according to `this.timeRange` value. The following change will make it work like that:

```js
const Ranges = {
  '1': () => format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
  '5': () => format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"),
  // etc.
};

if (Ranges[this.timeRange]) {
  Ranges[this.timeRange]();
}
```

So, `Ranges` becomes a set of formatters indexed by some ID. In the last `if` statement specific formatter is chosen and then executed (if it exists).